# Does Tasks.whenAllSuccess guarantee the order in which I pass tasks to it?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Cloud Firestore in an Android app.

I create 2 queries, one `whereLessThan` and one `whereGreaterThan` to effectively create an `!=` query.
I order the results for each individual query, but when I run them separately, I might get one or another returned first, depending on which is faster.

When I combine 2 queries into 1 and then use the `Tasks.whenAllSuccess` method to get 1 `Task` and add 1 `OnSuccessListener` to it, will it keep up the order of results in which I pass my tasks?

```
public void loadNotes(View v) {
    Task task1 = notebookRef
            .whereLessThan("priority", 2)
            .orderBy("priority")
            .get();

    Task task2 = notebookRef
            .whereGreaterThan("priority", 2)
            .orderBy("priority")
            .get();

    Task finalTask = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(task1, task2).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Object> objects) {
            //will my results be ordered prioty 1 - 3 - 4 - 5....?
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tasks.whenAllSuccess (and other whenAll methods) will deliver the results from the tasks to the callback in a List in the order they were passed to whenAllSuccess.  If you need some other way of getting the results, you can maintain some data structure with the original Task objects, then query them as you want.

Comment: Thank you. Is this the appropriate way to merge multiple queries? There is almost no documentation about it. I've been searching for hours.

Comment: If you want a single point of contact for the completion of a collection of tasks, this is the right way to do it.  See also this multi-part blog series.  https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I see this is for the Realtime Database, but I guess it also applies to Firestore? I wish there was more exact documentation, I stumpled upon these methods by accident.

Comment: This is for all Firebase and Play services libraries that use Tasks.  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks

Comment: Thanks, that looks helpful. But it seems that  continueWith is the better approach to chain 2 tasks. What do you think?

Comment: Whatever suits your needs.

Comment: But I am still suspicious if whenAllSuccess actually guarantees to return the results in a particular order. They just write it gets triggered when all tasks are successful

Comment: That's the whole point of whenAll methods - to get notified when **everything** is complete.

Comment: Yea, but the important part is that I get the results in the correct order, not just getting them when they are all complete. But I didn't read the whole blog yet, maybe the answer is in there.

Comment: The List in the callback has them in the order they were given as arguments.  That much was previously established in my answer.

Comment: Ok sorry that I didn't get it. Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask 2 more things? The OnCompleteListener returns a List of Objects. Can I just cast these objects into QuerySnapshots?
And the continueWith method waits until 1 tasks is finished, right? So if I want to execute both Tasks in parallel, it's better to not use it?

Comment: SO is not appropriate for extended conversations.  If you have followup questions, please post them as separate questions here, so that they can be easier to to search and that others may benefit.

Comment: @FlorianWalther So, did you find the answer to your 2 more questions?

Comment: @FlorianWalther So, did you find the answer to your 2 more questions?